# How to mix f-string and LaTeX symbols in a print(...) statement?

Tags: python, printing, latex, f-string

I am calculating pi with the Monte Carlo "quarter circle" method, using the following program:

```
from random import random as rd

def estimPi(n_points):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(n_points):
        x,y = rd(),rd()
        if x**2 + y**2 < 1:
            counter = counter + 1
    estimPi = 4*(counter/n_points)

    print(f'with {n_points} draws, the estimated value of pi is {estimPi}')
```

So that:

```
estimPi(10000)
```

gives me (as an example, of course):

```
with 10000 draws, the estimated value of pi is 3.1304
```

I would like to modify the `print(...)` line in order to have the pi symbol in the text printed, instead of having the string `"pi"`.

I tried:

```
print(f'with {n_points} draws, the estimated value of ' + r'$ \pi $' + f' is {estimPi}')
```

but it doesn't give me what I expect:

```
with 10000 draws, the estimated value of $ \pi $ is 3.1276
```

Is there a way to mix f-strings and LaTeX symbols in a `print(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the unicode symbol for that?

```
    print(f'with {n_points} draws, the estimated value of \u03C0 is {estimPi}')
```

output:
with 10000 draws, the estimated value of π is 3.1164

Comment: You're absolutely right; I hadn't even thought of that... Thanks